# Add a booking date in the sale of a ticket by paypal

Tags: html, wordpress, paypal

I'm going to sell tickets by paypal.
But I need to know in what day the client want to come.

I'm using Wordpress, and I have used several plugins but none has helped me.
Now I'm testing with html forms, but not how to do it.

If someone could help me or give me a clue how to fix it, I would be very grateful.

thank you very much!!

Comment: What pay-pal API are you currently using? There's a few available.

Answer (score 0):

In any of the plugin you installed, check the form that is passing data to the `paypal` add custom fields to it and elaborate the plugin according to your requirement then.

Check how the plugin is fetching values from paypal(return values) pass and retrieve what you need. Its just a basic idea, provide some code so that we can help you in better way.